# Handling client side "server sent" requests in a NodeJS backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express.js to handle http client requests, for the sake of simplicity please find a simplified version of the JavaScript code, depicting the issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/sayhi',(request,response)=>{
    response.end('ok')
});
```

when calling '/sayhi' from a REST client, there is no problem, however, I went into a situation where the business logic requires live data update, thus the client should poll the server constantly through server sent Events.
A server sent client request has the following format:

"http://localhost:8081/ServerSent.aspx?params={%myquery%22:%22sayhi%22}"

I have managed catch and filter the incoming request through app.use(),
 but was unable to find a way to call the '/sayhi' method.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>
{
 if (req.query.params != undefined)
 {
    if (JSON.parse(req.query.params).myquery == 'sayhi')
    {
    // I need a way to call the /sayhi post method.
    }
 }
});
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: can you update the url `http://localhost:8081/ServerSent.aspx?params={%myquery%22:%22sayhi%22}` by adding /sayhi path into it?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: then you can hit /sayhi

Comment: No, it does not work that way, parameters are sent as a query string for the request, so 'sayhi' is just a string value within the parameters. There is no way to hit /sayhi method. On the other hand, 'sayhi' is a POST http request, while the serversent request is GET.

Comment: so the usual way to hit `app.post('/sayhi'...)` is from a browser or some other client / may be the server itself. but here you can invoke the function inside `if (JSON.parse(req.query.params).myquery == 'sayhi'){}`. calling your app.post path inside middleware doesn't make any sense.